# Change value of TextBox when SelectedIndex of a ComboBox is changed via ViewModel properties only

Tags: wpf, combobox

I have a `ComboBox` and a `TextBox`. Both of them receive values (ie `SelectedValue` and `Text`) via `DataBinding` to corresponding `properties` in `ViewModel`.
Upon changing the `SelectedValue` in this `ComboBox`, I want to populate a new value in this `TextBox` from a `List<string>`(which is part of the `ViewModel`).
I don't want to use `SelectedIndexChanged` `event` of `ComboBox` here to select the new `TextBox`. `Text` from `List<string>` of `ViewModel`. How can I do this?

Comment: Bind selectedindex combobox property to viewmodel property and set your text in selectedindex setter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the setter of SelectedValue you should modify the value of the Text property and in setter of Text the PropertyChanged event shoud be fired.

```
    public string SelectedValue
    {
        get { return _selectedValue; }
        set
        {
            _selectedValue = value;
            //here write your code to modify the Text property
        }
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set
        {
            _text = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Text);
        }
    }
```

Comment: tx yevgeniy and jannagy.I was able to follow your leads.However,one thing that i am still unable to appreciate(maybe bec this is my first mvvm+wpf project) is that sometimes we need to do so much in mvvm and databinding that was otherwise possible just with one or two line of code.tx anywasy though...:-).